# How can one determine the appropriate meaning of 伺う in formal speech?

Tags: nuances, verbs, keigo

Is it based on the particle connecting the object of the verb?

For example,

> **に/へ**伺う
>
> to go

vs

> **を**伺う
>
> to ask

Is it **purely** based on the **context** of the sentence for distinguishing between `to go`, `to come`, and `to visit` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific_speech_in_Japanese#Respectful_verbs))?

Comment: You already understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dictionary, the word 伺う has 5 possible meanings, many of them using を.
So you have to look at the context to find the right meaning. 
Looking only at the particle may not be enough. Some sentences may not even have a particle.
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/伺う/#je-5174](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%BC%BA%E3%81%86/#je-5174)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/18016/meaning/m0u/伺う/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/18016/meaning/m0u/%E4%BC%BA%E3%81%86/)
https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BC%BA%E3%81%86-439046

But if you have:
someplaceへ伺う 
it will most certainly be "to visit".

Comment: Perhaps it is best to think of  へ伺う as 'movement toward' something, which would encompass 'to go / come / visit'.